# How to create a custom Balloon for Google Earth?

Tags: google-maps, javascript, google-earth

I just came across one question related to google maps in stackoverflow.

[Google Maps: How to create a custom InfoWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860277/google-maps-how-to-create-a-custom-infowindow)

I really like the popup that they mentioned in the question and the image is as follows.

Question: How to create or use same popup(InfoWindow) in google Earth.Is there any way to achieve this?

**IMAGE:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also a tutorial [here](http://earth.google.com/outreach/tutorial_balloon.html) on customizing balloons in Google Earth.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have seen this link and tried to use the templates in the tutorial.But i am not able to get the design as in image which is pasted the above.

Comment: It may not be possible to change the shape of the balloon corners, at least I have not seen any indication that it IS possible.

Comment: Yes i tried a lot to get the solution.But i didnt.

Comment: Hope that this is not a bug.So,i thought that somebody knows the things in right manner to get the popup as above.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the mapface library:
http://mapface.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually mapface is using for google maps.But i need on google earth.